# Unidirectional or bidirectional relationships in JPA?

Tags: jpa, associations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Unidirectional and Bidirectional associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360795/what-is-the-difference-between-unidirectional-and-bidirectional-associations)

Under which circumstances or which criteria should I follow in order to choose between unidirectional and bidirectional relationships in JPA?

Comment: Errm, if a relation is unidirectional (i.e one side needs to know of the other) then you make it that, and if bidirectional (both sides need to know of the other) then do that. JPA is there simply to reflect your model. and. nothing. else.

Comment: Having an association, even if not exposed to the outside, can also ease the writing od JPQL queries.