# Persisting with AngularJS and JPA

Tags: json, angularjs, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to develop an application using Google Guice, JPA (EclipseLink) and AngularJS.
Basically in this application I have some Employees and more than one Salary for each of them.

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID_EMPLOYEE")
private long idEmployee;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee",targetEntity = Salary.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Salary> salaries;
```

and the Salary object:

```
public class Salary implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID_SALARY")
private long idSalary;

@Column(name="SALARY_PA")
private String salaryPa;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_EMPLOYEE", referencedColumnName = "ID_EMPLOYEE")
private Employee employee;
```

Now, I'm able to insert, using angularJS and REST services, a new employee without any problem. What I can't do is adding a new salary to an existing employee. 
Basically what I have in my angularJS controller is:

```
$scope.employee.salaries.push(this.salaryToAdd);
employeeServ.persistSalary(employee);
```

and then I just save the employee. The salary is saved but when I try to get the Employee sometimes I can see the salary sometime not. What I noticed is that the salary doesn't have any reference to the Employee so maybe when I get the employee JPA doesn't know if the salary is related to that Employee.

This is my dao and the part related to the persistence:

```
public abstract class GenericDao<E> implements AbstractDao<E> {

@Inject
private EntityManager em;

protected abstract Class<E> getGenericClass();

@Transactional
@Override
public void insert(E entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void update(E entity) {
    em.merge(entity);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(E entity) {
    em.remove(entity);
}

public E findById(Long id) {
    Class<E> clazz = getGenericClass();
    return em.find(clazz, id);
}

public List<E> findAll() {
    Class<E> clazz = getGenericClass();
    CriteriaQuery<E> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(clazz);
    Root<E> root = query.from(clazz);
    query.select(root);
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}



@Path("/employee")
```

public class EmployeeProvider {

```
@Inject
EmployeeDao dao;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/get/{id}")
public String get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    if("all".equals(id)) {
        return gson.toJson(dao.findAll().toArray());
    } else {
        return gson.toJson(dao.findById(Long.valueOf(id)));
    }
}

@POST
@Path("/post")
public void post(String employee) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Employee entity = gson.fromJson(employee, Employee.class);
    dao.update(entity);
}
```

Comment: Your JPA mappings look correct and you don't need an `Employee` reference in `Salary`. That would just make it a [bi-directional relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5361587/2408961) as opposed to the uni-directional relationship you have now. Can you add the relevant sections of code that persist and read the `Employee` entity and then serialize to JSON?

Comment: Could you look whether the error comes from the Json-Deserializer or from the JPA merge method? (debug the post-method and look whether the entity is correct after json-deserialization)

Comment: I debugged and I didn't notice any issue on Json-deserializer. The problem is somewhere else because the entity deserialized is actually the one retrieved by the dao.
I was wondering, do I need to persist the salary and then add it to the employee?