# Update generated after insert when bidirectional one to many mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, one-to-many

I am using bidirectional one to many relationship mapping for performance reason in order to have only `inserts` generated when persisting entities (according to one of the answers from  [What is the difference between Unidirectional and Bidirectional JPA and Hibernate associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360795/what-is-the-difference-between-unidirectional-and-bidirectional-jpa-and-hibernat#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20unidirectional,or%20from%20the%20child%20side.)
)

However when I don't specify `CascadeType.PERSIST` on the many side I noticed that updates are still generated after inserts.

```
Hibernate: insert into promotion (deadline, description, percentage, promotion_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update product set amount_in_stock=?, category_id=?, description=?, product_name=?, product_price=?, production_year=?, promotion_id=?, "size"=?, sold_amount=?, vendor=?, weight=? where product_id=?
```

`Promotion` can refer to many `Product`s:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_id_sequence", sequenceName = "product_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "product_id_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long productId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
    @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id")
    private Promotion promotion;
   
    // setters, getters, other fields
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Promotion")
public class Promotion
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROMOTION_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "promotion_id_sequence", sequenceName = "promotion_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "promotion_id_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long promotionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "promotion", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addProduct(Product product)
    {
        products.add(product);
        product.setPromotion(this);
    }
    // setters, getters, delete synchronization method, other fields
}
```

Persist logic (`@DataJpaTest`):

```
promotion.addProduct(product);
entityManager.persist(promotion);
entityManager.flush();
```

Why it happens?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening, because in the test I was persisting several more entities which had relationship to `Product`. Then when `Product` was in manged state, by invoking `entityManager.persist(promotion);` hibernate had to update `Product` by adding `promotion_id` key.

```java
entityManager.persist(category); // category has many products (CascadeType.ALL added)
entityManager.persist(promotion);
entityManager.flush();
```

I should have provided more lines of the test method, but frankly speaking I was not aware that they have some influence. So summing it up, it was not a problem of mapping, but an order of persisting the entities with relationships to one another. And finally

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id")
private Promotion promotion;
```

is correct, that is no additional cascade required on the `Product` side.